# The group of pure/hereditary sets

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

From wikipedia:

> In set theory, a hereditary set (or pure set) is a set all of whose
>   elements are hereditary sets. That is, all elements of the set are
>   themselves sets, as are all elements of the elements, and so on.

So, sets like $\emptyset,\ \{\emptyset\},\ \{\{\emptyset\}\},\ \{\{\emptyset\},\ \emptyset\}\ ...$

It's easy to see that if you take the set $S$ of all the finite pure sets (whose elements are also finite pure sets) and equip it with the operation of symmetric difference $A \triangle B = \left(A\cup B\right) \setminus \left(A\cap B\right) = \left(A\setminus B\right)\cup\left(B\setminus A\right)$ you obtain an infinite group.

My question is, how do I approach this group to understand its structure?
So far I've only found out some of its subgroups (free abelian groups on $n$ elements where each element has order 2), but I'm sure there's much more to it

Comment: $S$ is not a set. You get a set if you restrict to, for example, the *hereditarily finite* sets, that is, those pure sets that are finite, and all their elements are finite, and all the elements of their elements are finite, etc.

Comment: Oh thanks, I meant that with "finite pure sets", I'll correct it now

Comment: $A \triangle \emptyset = A$ and $A \triangle A = \emptyset$, so this group contains no free abelian subgroups, right?

Comment: You are right, they are abelian subgroups where each element has order 2, like the Klein-4 group... Does these have a specific name so I can edit the question?

Comment: Yes, it is an elemenary abelian 2-group. It has the structure of a vector space over the field with two elements, so a decent version of the question is "What is a basis?"

Comment: (A different question is "This is a (not complete) boolean lattice. What sort of lattice properties does it have? Where can I read about such lattices?")

Comment: @JackSchmidt I'll read about boolean lattices then... I was curious about more "classical" approaches to understand this group though